# using Visual studio Team services in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have been using Visual studio 2013.  Is it possible to use visual studio Team services (Not TFS ) in Visual studio 2013?

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can easily be self-answered by trying first.

Comment: Have you connected your VSTS repo in VS2013 so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible.

First you should **connect your VSTS account in VS**:

VS -> Team Explorer -> Manage connections -> input your VSTS account and password -> connect the repo you want to work with.

- If you are work with VSTS **Git repo** in VS2013, you can refer [Get started using Git in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/get-started-vs2013) for detail operations.
- If you are work with **TFVC repo** in VS2013, you can refer [Develop and share your code in TFVC using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs) for detail operations.